# Connection to localhost with bad port : 1s delay

Tags: java, servlets

My servlet connects to another http server on the same host, and this second http server is sometimes down which is normal. Here is my code:

```
URL test = new URL("http://localhost:1234/");
try (InputStream is = test.openStream();) {
} catch(IOException e) {
    // not started
}
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
```

When the server is not started, I get a java.net.ConnectException but this exception only comes after approximately 1s. This is annoying because I'd like to test if the server is started in all my servlets.
Where does this delay come from?
For information I'm running Windows, I guess this delay may be platform-dependant.
Edit : Ubuntu does not have this delay and the exception throws immediately

Of course, I do not want to decrease the connection timeout, because the server could be up and answer in more than 1s.

Thanks

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps 1 second is the amount of time the API actually needs to be able to tell you that the connection is really down.

Comment: you can have another scheduler just to check whether the server is running or not and maintain a status every 5 mins or so. You can use that status in your servlet.

Comment: probably it is related with timers for TCP connection. Check the parameters by obtaining the connection first and see the value for, example, getConnectTimeout().

Comment: Try getting first an URLConnection from the URL object and then set the connectionTimeout for that connection to only some mili secs before you connect. Otherwiese the defaults will be used.

Comment: You could reduce the timeout duration by editing the [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout(int)) you get from `test.openConnection()`.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Windows should know that nothing is listening on port 1234 and so it should take no time to answer

Comment: @Rene M : I don't want to decrease timeout value because if the server is up and takes more than 1s to answer, I don't want to get an error

Comment: @Obi Wan - PallavJha : this is the only solution I could find, but I'm not happy with it